# Spring data jpa how to re-use @NamedEntityGraph?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = CITY_BASIC, attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("state"),
                @NamedAttributeNode("country")
        }),
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = CITY_DETAILS, attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("state"),
                @NamedAttributeNode("country"),
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "suburbs", subgraph = "basic")
        },
                subgraphs = @NamedSubgraph(name = CITY_BASIC, attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode("state"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("country")
                }))
})
public class City {
  private String name;
  private State state;
  private Set<City> suburbs;
}
```

another class which has City object, e.g.

```
public class Address {
  private String street;
  private City city;
}
```

If I want the entity graph of `Address` to use the existing `CITY_BASIC` or `CITY_DETAILS` entity graph in the subgraph, what should I do?

Comment: Sure, using name of the original graph.

Comment: It can only be called whithin same class.